# Atomic MySQL transactions in Anorm

Tags: mysql, scala, anorm

I have written a simple hit counter, that updates a MySQL database table using Anorm.  I want the transaction to be atomic.  I think that the best way would be to join all of the SQL strings together and do one query, but this doesn't seem to be possible with Anorm.  Instead I have placed each select, update and commit on separate lines.  This works but I can't help thinking that their must be a better way.

```
private def incrementHitCounter(urlName:String) {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("start transaction;").executeUpdate()
    SQL("select @hits:=hits from content_url_name where url_name={urlName};").on("urlName" -> urlName).apply()
    SQL("update content_url_name set hits = @hits + 1 where url_name={urlName};").on("urlName" -> urlName).executeUpdate()
    SQL("commit;").executeUpdate()
  }
}
```

Can anyone see a better way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Use `withTransaction` instead of `withConnection` like this:

```
private def incrementHitCounter(urlName:String) {
  DB.withTransaction { implicit connection =>
    SQL("select @hits:=hits from content_url_name where url_name={urlName};").on("urlName" -> urlName).apply()
    SQL("update content_url_name set hits = @hits + 1 where url_name={urlName};").on("urlName" -> urlName).executeUpdate()
  }
}
```

And why would you even use a transaction here? This should work as well:

```
private def incrementHitCounter(urlName:String) {
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL("update content_url_name set hits = (select hits from content_url_name where url_name={urlName}) + 1 where url_name={urlName};").on("urlName" -> urlName).executeUpdate()
  }
}
```