# How to do SQL Transactions with anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

Currently I`m working in a project and I need to know how to do SQL transactions in anorm. If anybody has an idea how to do it?

Comment: This might be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431841/atomic-mysql-transactions-in-anorm

Comment: Anorm doesn't manage JDBC connections.